# Met `Solving environment: failed` error when doing `conda env`

Tags: python, anaconda

I have python 3.7 and latest anaconda.(MacOS 10.14.5)

I am having Solving environment: failed issue with this error code.

```
ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - twisted==17.5.0=py36_0
```

could anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

```
conda env create -f cvcourse_macos.yml 


(base) Simons-MacBook-Pro:~ paladalgom$ cd Downloads
    (base) Simons-MacBook-Pro:Downloads paladalgom$ conda env create -f cvcourse_macos.yml 
    Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
    Solving environment: failed

    ResolvePackageNotFound: 
      - twisted==17.5.0=py36_0

(base) Simons-MacBook-Pro:Downloads paladalgom$ - twisted==17.5.0=py36_0
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the file `cvcourse_macos.yml` with your favourite editor.

If you are newer to programming, try [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com) or [Atom](https://atom.io).

The `.yml` file may have the following structure:

```
name: python-cvcourse
channels:
  ...
dependencies:
  ...
  - pip=10.0.1=py36_0
  ...
```

Under the that `pip=10.0.1=py36_0` line add:

```
  - pip=10.0.1=py36_0:
    - twisted==17.5.0=py36_0
```

Notice the `:` after `- pip=10.0.1=py36_0` and the 4 spaces or indentation for the next line.

The dependency `twisted==17.5.0=py36_0` will be somewhere in the dependencies list, delete that other occurrence and keep the one you added.

After that, save your file and run `conda env create -f cvcourse_macos.yml` again.

**Alternative:**

That concrete `python-cvcourse` is part of a Computer Vision course in Udemy. I've done it and can say: feel free to delete the `"twisted=17.5,0=py36_0"` line. You will not need it. The `tbb..` one as well, as, dependiing on conda version, runs against an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

In `env.yml` of conda, put `twisted==17.5.0=py36_0` under `pip` section.

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner for using anaconda so could you explain the details?
how do I find env.yml file? and pip?

Comment: Okay, I think you can have an idea about it by reading on this article. https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html . Usually conda creates a virtual env, with some specific configurations to it, it is ismilar to python-venv. So the inside configs are isolated from the global ones. env.yml should be located at your app's root directory